# SQL insertion in batch for million records instead of row by row insertion in tables

Tags: mysql, sql, database, batch-processing

Question :
**Currently my insertion process is very slow and its takes long time to insert the data into database, instead of row by row insertion i wanted to achieve batch insertion, How can i achieve same **?
CODE : This is schema of the table :

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS dorepeat;

```
DELIMITER ;;

CREATE PROCEDURE dorepeat(IN p1 INT, IN p2 INT, IN p3 INT, IN p4 INT, IN p5 INT, IN p6 INT, IN p7 INT, IN p8 INT, IN p9 INT, IN P10 INT)
BEGIN
DECLARE x INT DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE url VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT '';
DECLARE id INT DEFAULT NULL;
DECLARE y INT DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE z INT DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE k INT DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE l INT DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE m INT DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE n INT DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE o INT DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE tagId INT DEFAULT NULL;
DECLARE accountId INT DEFAULT NULL;
DECLARE imageId INT DEFAULT NULL;
DECLARE campaignId INT DEFAULT NULL;
DECLARE hashId INT DEFAULT NULL;
DECLARE productId INT DEFAULT NULL;
DECLARE userId INT DEFAULT NULL;

INSERT INTO `auth_user`(password,last_login,is_superuser,username,first_name,last_name,email,is_staff,is_active,date_joined) VALUES ('12',now(),1,UUID(),'first','last','email',1,1,now());
SET userId = LAST_INSERT_ID();


INSERT INTO `server_tag`(name) VALUES('123');
SET tagId = LAST_INSERT_ID();

SET o = 0; REPEAT 
    INSERT INTO `server_account`(`name`,`key`,`account_id`) VALUES (LEFT(MD5(o), 30), '1', 1);
    SET accountId = LAST_INSERT_ID();

    SET n = 0; REPEAT 
        INSERT INTO `server_campaign`(name,app_id,app_name,`access_key`,`secret_key`,`meta_config`,`full_text_searchable`,`updated`,`created`,`account_id`) 
        VALUES 
        (LEFT(MD5(n), 30), 
        1,
         '123', 
         '123',
         '123', 
         '123', 
         1, 
         now(), 
         now(), 
         accountId
         );
        SET campaignId = LAST_INSERT_ID();

        SET m = 0; REPEAT 
            INSERT INTO `server_hashtag`(NAME, status) VALUES (LEFT(MD5(m), 50), 1);
            SET hashId = LAST_INSERT_ID();

            SET l = 0; REPEAT
                SET url = CONCAT('http://example.com/', MD5(CONCAT(hashId, ':', l)));
                INSERT INTO `server_image`(hex, url, low_url, thumbnail_url, box, username, link, posted, updated, status, score, hashtag_id)
                VALUES (
                SHA1(url),
                url,
                CONCAT('a', hashId),
                CONCAT('b', hashId),
                CONCAT('c', hashId),
                CONCAT('d', hashId),
                CONCAT('e', hashId),
                NOW(),
                NOW(),
                1,
                CONCAT('f', hashId),
                hashId
                );
                SET imageId = LAST_INSERT_ID();

                SET k = 0; REPEAT 
                    INSERT INTO `server_product`(im_name, meta) VALUES (LEFT(UUID(), 1000000), 1);
                    SET productId = LAST_INSERT_ID();


                    INSERT INTO `server_image_product`(campaign_id, image_id, product_id) VALUES (campaignId,imageId,productId);
                    INSERT INTO `server_image_status`(status,updated,campaign_id,image_id,user_id) VALUES(2,now(),campaignId,imageId,userId);
                    INSERT INTO `server_image_tag`(campaign_id,image_id,tag_id) VALUES (campaignId, imageId, tagId);


                    SET k = k + 1;
                UNTIL k >= p7 END REPEAT;

                SET l = l + 1;
            UNTIL l >= p6 END REPEAT;

            SET m = m + 1;
        UNTIL m >= p5 END REPEAT;

        SET n = n + 1;
    UNTIL n >= p4 END REPEAT;

    SET o = o + 1;
UNTIL o >= p3 END REPEAT;

END;;

DELIMITER ;

SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;
TRUNCATE TABLE `auth_user`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `server_tag`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `server_image`; 
TRUNCATE TABLE `server_hashtag`; 
TRUNCATE TABLE `server_product`; 
TRUNCATE TABLE `server_account`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `server_campaign`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `server_image_product`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `server_image_status`;
TRUNCATE TABLE `server_image_tag`;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1;


CALL dorepeat(1, 1, 100, 100, 100, 1000000, 1000000, 100, 100, 100);
```

Question :
**Currently my insertion process is very slow and its takes long time to insert the data into database, instead of row by row insertion i wanted to achieve batch insertion, How can i achieve same **?

Comment: [link] _DBMS_: **Mysql**

Comment: `SET l = 0; REPEAT,SET url = CONCAT('http://example.com/', MD5(CONCAT(hashId, ':', y)));
INSERT INTO `server_image`(hex, url, l_url, t_url, box, username, link, posted, updated, status, score, hashtag_id)
VALUES (SHA1(url),url,CONCAT('a', hashId),CONCAT('b', hashId),CONCAT('c', hashId),CONCAT('d', hashId),CONCAT('e', hashId),NOW(),NOW(),1,CONCAT('f', hashId),hashId);
SET imageId = LAST_INSERT_ID();SET k = 0; REPEAT INSERT INTO `server_product`(im_name, meta) VALUES (LEFT(MD5(k), 50), 1);
SET productId = LAST_INSERT_ID();` this two record needed to generate 1 Million records in database